# Having problems while try to install OAUTH with PECL in MAMP on mac OS lion

Tags: php, oauth, mamp, pecl

i am new to setting php servers, and i had go though other related post, seems like nobody have the same error as i have.
I am using MAMP 2.0.2, and running PHP 5.3.6,
and I was trying to install oAuth on my local MAMP, using following commands:

```
$ cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin
$ ./pecl install oauth
```

however, it return such error:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 276 of 1133 bytes in Config.php on line 1050
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted.
```

What is happening? PECL is bundled in MAMP, which should be working out of the box....

Update:

I read a post elsewhere suggest that the config file's data, which holds the install paths are in-correct, so i changed some value in the following file :

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf
```

Then, i use the command:

```
$ ./pecl install oauth
```

Which it starts download and unpack, but when it try to install, it gives:

```
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-user1RU5EZA/oauth-1.2.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-user1RU5EZA/oauth-1.2.2/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-user1RU5EZA/oauth-1.2.2/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -g   -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth/oauth.c -o oauth.lo
mkdir .libs
cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-user1RU5EZA/oauth-1.2.2/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-user1RU5EZA/oauth-1.2.2/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -g -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth/oauth.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/oauth.o
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth/oauth.c:14:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth/php_oauth.h:20:10: 

fatal error: 'php.h' file not found

include "php.h"
     ^

1 error generated.

make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1

ERROR: `make' failed
```

Again, what is happening?

Answer (score 66):

I know this is old but I found this question while having a similar issue.

> MAMP doesn’t ship with a bunch of the PHP sources

- Download MAMP components and configure
- URL: http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html (i.e. MAMP_components_2.0.2.zip)
- Unpack your MAMP_components_2.0.2.zip
- Identify your php-5.x.x.tar.gz file (where 5.x.x is your version of PHP)
- If you are using php > 5.4.10 then download the sources from http://php.net/releases as they are not in the MAMP components download (credit pulkitsinghal in comments)
- Create directory for your PHP sources:

  `mkdir -vp /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/include`
- Untar php-5.x.x.tar.gz into /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.*/include or /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/ include:

  `tar zxvf php-5.x.x.tar.gz -C /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.?.??/include`
- Rename your php-5.x.x directory to php (without the version numbering):

  `mv /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/include/php-5.?.?? /Applications/
       MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/include/php`
- Configure PHP sources (it’ll create necessary files i.e. zend_config.h, tsrm_config.h, etc.):

  `cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.?.??/include/php`

  `./configure`

The process was for another fix but this resolved the issues with php.h not being found

Credit to where I found the answers - :

[Thomas Hunter Blog](http://thomashunter.name/blog/getting-the-php-mongodb-driver-installed-with-mamp-on-os-x/)

[Google Doc detailing process](http://thomashunter.name/blog/getting-the-php-mongodb-driver-installed-with-mamp-on-os-x/)

Comment: This didn't work for me but didn't have time to dig in any further.

Comment: thanks a lot - i used this to get the php mongo driver installed with php 5.4.4

Comment: If you get the following `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend/zend.h:51:11: fatal error: 'zend_config.h' file not found` make sure you configure php sources. i.e. in the directory where you copied all the files run ./configure

Comment: Well i'm using MAMP 2.2 now, where do i get the component.zip??

Comment: the only tweak is that MAMP_components_2.1.2 didn't have the zip for php5.5.3 so that had to be retrieved from http://www.php.net/releases/ instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. You saved my life. I used this structure to get mongo driver installed with php 5.5.26

Comment: I was so sure this would work... but after running ./configure:  configure: error: build test failed.  Please check the config.log for details.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17428145/config_log.txt

Comment: I would really like to try this solution but I cant seem to find the MAMP_component zip file,  When I go to the url suggested all i get is a pkg file

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem whilst trying to `pecl install -f ssh2` with MAMP.

Here's how I fixed it:

1. MAMP doesn't provide the source code archive for PHP 5.4.10 so download it from [php.net](http://www.php.net/releases/)
2. Extract the source code archive to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/include/php
3. Run `./configure` to configure the source code for your platform (without this step the pecl install will fail looking for a bunch of header files)
4. Retry your `pecl` install

(much thanks to Stephen's answer which is pretty much the same)

Comment: This is the simpler answer. One thing to note: rename the uncompressed PHP 5.4.10 folder to simply `php` after placing it into the `/include` directory, I was confused about that step.

Comment: This answer should be accepted, it fixes the issue, is clearly explained and I guess it will work for a long time. Not like the most voted one.

Comment: But running these commands in the terminal don't affect the MAMP installation but the system installation of PHP which doesn't appear to help me.

Answer (score 6):

This is a complement to Stephen's answer and Greg's comment

When compiling xdebug 2.3.2 for php 5.6.2 on OSX 10.10.2, I could not get rid of the

> 'zend_config.h' file not found

error until I added the following option to ./configure in the php folder:

> ./configure --without-iconv

[Credits to Cameron Browning](http://www.5cameron.com/content/installing-php-uploadprogress-mac-os-109-mavericks)

Answer (score 1):

PECL Modules are compiled modules, in order to install them, you need the PHP headers. You can found the headers on php.net/downloads.php make sure you download a version which match with your PHP version. Then you can follow this : [Installing PHP OAuth in MAMP environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413380/installing-php-oauth-in-mamp-environment/24275145)