# installing pecl - fatal error: 'php.h' file not found

Tags: php, macos, oauth, pecl

I'm trying to install PECL OAuth but I get an error message (I use macbook mountain lion).

```
 In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth/oauth.c:14:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/oauth/php_oauth.h:20:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Someone know how to solve it?

Thanks,
Nimi

Comment: Do you have the php headers installed? (In debian it's imply installing php5-dev, in OSX: dunno, but there must be an equivalent)

Comment: You need the PHP development package / source code / whatever it's called for OSX.

Comment: I use MAMP. I have installed PECL and PEAR. Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having problems while try to install OAUTH with PECL in MAMP on mac OS lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717752/having-problems-while-try-to-install-oauth-with-pecl-in-mamp-on-mac-os-lion)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583810/unable-to-install-mongodb-php-driver-on-mac-os-10-9

Comment: @Nimi Did you solve this issue?