# Unable to install mongodb php driver on mac os 10.9

Tags: php, macos, mongodb

After googling for about an hour can't find any solution that works for me. I'm on OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Here is what the terminal says:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongo

downloading mongo-1.4.4.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.4.4.tgz (141,242 bytes)
..............................done: 141,242 bytes
84 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable Mongo extension... yes, shared
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether to compile for recent osx architectures... yes
checking whether to include code coverage symbols... no
checking Build with PHP streams support... yes
checking for ld used by cc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin13.0.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/libtool --mode=compile cc -I./util -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/util -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/util -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/exceptions -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/exceptions -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/gridfs -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/gridfs -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/types -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/types -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/mcon -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/mcon  -
DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5   -c /private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/php_mongo.c -o php_mongo.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I./util -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/util -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/util -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/exceptions -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/exceptions -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/gridfs -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/gridfs -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/types -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/types -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootDzh2iw/mongo-1.4.4/mcon -I/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/mcon -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -c /private/tmp/pea
r/install/mongo/php_mongo.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/php_mongo.o
/private/tmp/pear/install/mongo/php_mongo.c:16:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include <php.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_mongo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Maybe someone has already encountered this problem and knows a solution?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Unfortunately your question is not a good fit for this website, because stackoverflow is about programming problems only. There are, however, several other websites of the stackexchange network where your question would be much more appropriate.

Comment: @Philipp, although this is clearly to do with installing software, I don't agree that the question is not a good fit for this site.  After all, the software being installed will be for development purposes on that platform, and it very relevant to other developers upgrading to Mavericks on Mac.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After upgrading to OS 10.9 I run into same issue.
Try installing command line developer tools

run

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server."

Comment: I second @JohnJ.Camilleri. This worked perfectly for me after upgrading to OSX Mavericks

Comment: You my friend, are a god.

Comment: "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates"

Comment: This got me past the missing php.h file, but then it got stuck looking for openssl.h. Running the following command worked.

`sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include pecl install mongodb`

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I solved this after installing Xcode:

```
cd /usr/include
sudo ln -sf /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/php
```

Comment: ln: ./php: Operation not permitted

Comment: @Ahmadster what if we get  ./php: Operation not permitted ?

Answer (score 1):

If the solution by Janis Lankovskis did not work out.. then it seems like your PHP installation is weirdly broken..

How did you install PHP in the first place?

The main problem here is the `phpize` command, which seems to exist but if failing miserably (I don't know why `pecl` continues.. that seems weird).

I'd re-install PHP, and make sure the header files are available - and in case you have multiple installations then make the path of the `phpize` command for your "currently active" PHP installation the first path in your $PATH

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article very helpful](http://lukepeters.me/blog/setting-up-mongodb-with-php-and-mamp). Saved a lot of time after I wasted a lot of time to check other links.

The thing is MAMP does not ship with all PHP sources to compile pecl mongo file and create mongo.so. All what you need is download php for respective version you are using. I was using php version `5.6.10`. I checked php.net site that was having `5.6.13` version. I downloaded sources for this version from [PhP.net](http://www.php.net/downloads.php). Executed "`sudo pecl install mongo`" again and it worked.

Comment: the article url is broken or not relevant anymore

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/php
$ brew install php56-mongodb
```

Then add this to your php.ini

extension='/usr/local/opt/**php56-mongodb**/mongodb.so'

Notice that I am installing "php56-mongodb" and also linking to the same on php.ini. You can change that to your preferred php version.