# Installing pecl,pear and xde on mamp

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug

I am trying to install pecl,pearl and xdebug on mamp 2.1.2. I have tried almost everything but even when xdebug appear in phpinfo it doesn't seem to work. I tried it for netbeans too but nothing. I am a new to mac and really frustrated on how to run it and make a local project of mine debug using breakpoints. can someone help me figure it out on how to make pecl,pear and xdebug on my OSX so i can debug my project.

Comment: I found this solution very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11175197/369326

Answer (score 1):

Check this link :

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-on-mamp-mac-os-x-107-lion

**Edit**

MAMP doesn’t ship with a bunch of the PHP sources

```
Download MAMP components and configure    
URL: http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html (i.e. MAMP_components_2.0.2.zip)
Unpack your MAMP_components_2.0.2.zip
Identify your php-5.x.x.tar.gz file (where 5.x.x is your version of PHP)
Create directory for your PHP sources: "mkdir -vp /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/include"
Untar php-5.x.x.tar.gz into /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.*/include or /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/ include e.g. tar zxvf php-5.x.x.tar.gz -C /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.?.??/include

Rename your php-5.x.x directory to php (without the version numbering) e.g. mv /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/include/php-5.?.?? /Applications/ MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/include/php

Configure PHP sources (it’ll create necessary files i.e. zend_config.h, tsrm_config.h, etc.)

cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.?.??/include/php ./configure
```

The process was for another fix but this resolved the issues with php.h not being found

Comment: i did the component things bt after last line i didn't got any prompt.is that right? and i m unable to understand this "The path can be modified by editing the ".profile" file under your home directory" where can i find .profile?