# Can't phpize or configure an extension in OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: php, macos, php-extension, osx-mavericks

I am trying to build the memcached extension on OS X 10.9 Mavericks for use with the built in PHP 5.4, initially I tried `pecl install memcached` but that threw the following.

```
checking for zlib location... configure: error: memcached support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify the prefix where ZLIB headers and library are located
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/memcached/configure' failed
```

So I created a tmp directory and executed `pecl download memcached`, unzipped the code and cd'd to the appropriate directory.

Trying to phpize it returned the following:

```
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

I had brew installed zlib a while ago and pointed ./configure at my installation.
`./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8` I was greeted with the following error message:

```
checking for session includes... configure: error: Cannot find php_session.h
```

So now I'm wondering the best course of action here... `/usr/include/` doesn't exist at all... is this a Mavericks thing? I don't remember having this problem in 10.8 at all.

I could try brew installing `php-devel` but I presume that isn't going to be the right version of what I need? Any help would be greatly appreciated here

#### Update

`locate php_session.h` reveals

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/php/ext/session/php_session.h`

should I just `ln -s` this to the expected location or is there some way to do this via XCode? I have the command line tools installed...

Answer (score 99, accepted):

run `xcode-select --install` to install the XCode5 Command Line Tools, then `sudo pecl install memcache`. You should be good to go.

Comment: I'm receiving 

xcode-select: error: invalid argument 'fixes'
Usage: xcode-select [options]

Comment: Holy cow, this worked for me too after an hour of searching.  Just for Google sake - this also solved a problem of trying to install apc and getting the error message:  /private/tmp/pear/install/APC/apc.h:61:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found.

Comment: If code-select --install doesn't work for you, you can download them as follows:
Open up Xcode
In the application menu item "Xcode" select Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools...
This takes you to a site with a bunch of software. Go ahead and download and install "Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode - Late October 2013".
(Copied from https://discussions.apple.com/message/23548005#23548005)

Comment: I am install `php-protocolbuffers` and getting `php.h` not foud. `xcode-select` already present

Answer (score 5):

After install XCode5 Command Line Tools as afessler sugest (xcode-select --install) I couldn't do the "sudo pecl install memcache" because pecl was missing.
I had to install PEAR and PECL following this guide: http://techtastico.com/post/como-instalar-pear-y-pecl-en-os-x-mavericks/.
Then all worked good. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it was due to MAMP not having all the PHP sources.

I found this really helpful solution that explains how to download and configure them:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175197/369326

Note that the MAMP components doesn't include the extras for any versions of PHP higher than php 5.4.10 but you can download the extras from http://php.net/releases.

Answer (score 0):

As said above but not using xcode install
Try installing pecl manually:

```
  curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar 
  sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

and then:

```
 sudo pecl install memcache
```

See more at: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/#sthash.x2LKdqj6.dpuf