# can't get PHP extensions to load on OS X Mavericks

Tags: php, php-extension, php-ini, osx-mavericks

So I upgraded to OS X 10.9 Mavericks and I'm trying to set up my local dev environment again. I ran `xcode-select --install` as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531262/cant-phpize-or-configure-an-extension-in-os-x-10-9-mavericks) which lets me compile the extensions successfully. I've confirmed that the extension exists in `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525` and that I've added `extension=redis.so` to my php.ini file.

I haven't seen any errors related to being unable to load the extension, and `phpinfo()` reports the expected extension_dir and shows a `extension=redis.so` in its output, confirming that I did put it into the correct file. Unfortunately that's the only trace of 'redis' in the `phpinfo()` output.

When I go to my application, I get the error:
`Fatal error: Class 'Redis' not found in /Volumes/Storage/ty/Sites/audiomack/application/Bootstrap.php on line 95`

I installed using `sudo pecl install redis` one time and by manually downloading the phpredis zip and compiling it myself once, same result.

Any ideas why PHP isn't loading extensions?

I am getting one strange warning that seems unrelated, but I will mention it for completeness: in php.ini I've set `date.timezone = America/New_York`, but my setting seems to be getting ignored. PHP info's "date" section shows date.timezone as 'no value' still, and gives me the warning we've all seen a hundred times:

`It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /Volumes/Storage/ty/Sites/audiomack/public/phpinfo.php on line 2`

**edit:** yes, I've restarted apache repeatedly, no dice

Comment: no idea about ther edis stuff, but for the timezone bits, make sure you're editting the correct .ini file. `phpinfo()`'s output will tell you which files are being parsed. you might have modified the one controlling CLI, but are using the SAPI .ini

Comment: arrrrrghhh... a missing quote on the include_path line of php.ini was the culprit. I'm shocked that there was no syntax/parse error thrown because of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ugh. the include_path line of the php.ini file had an opening quotation mark but no closing quote. PHP was sucking in most of the php.ini file as the value for include_path. Shocked that there weren't any syntax or parse errors thrown because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename php.ini.default -> php.ini and restart apache server: sudo apachectl restart