# Where to find MAMP server components and Libraries

Tags: mamp, pecl

I am trying to install pecl_http in MAMP php.
I am getting the following errors.

> grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
>   grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
>   grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
>   
> Configuring for:

Did a research on that and found out we need MAMP server components and Libraries.

After downloading this component, find the zip file corresponding to my version of PHP, extract it into a new directory in your PHP installation and run the configure script.

All the posts I saw points to this link http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/ . But I cant find anything there. And in few other links I found the components for older versions php (till 5.3).

This installation depend on too many things and takes a lot of time. Please let me know, if any one know where can I find these **MAMP SERVER components and Libraries** for PHP5.5.10

Attaching most of the output lines created in my terminal FYI.

> $ sudo pecl install pecl_http
>   Password:
>   downloading pecl_http-2.0.6.tgz ...
>   Starting to download pecl_http-2.0.6.tgz (152,827 bytes)
>   ......................done: 152,827 bytes
>   downloading raphf-1.0.4.tgz ...
>   Starting to download raphf-1.0.4.tgz (7,232 bytes)
>   ...done: 7,232 bytes
>   downloading propro-1.0.0.tgz ...
>   Starting to download propro-1.0.0.tgz (6,217 bytes)
>   ...done: 6,217 bytes
>   4 source files, building
>   WARNING: php_bin /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php appears to have a suffix /php5.5.10/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
>   running: phpize
>   grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
>   grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
>   grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
>   
> Configuring for:
>   PHP Api Version:
>   Zend Module Api No:
>   Zend Extension Api No:
>   whether to enable raphf support [yes] : yes
>   building in /usr/local/pear/pear-build-rootXNkOc5/raphf-1.0.4
>   running: /usr/local/pear/raphf/configure --enable-raphf=yes
>   checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
>   checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
>   checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
>   checking for cc... cc
>   checking whether the C compiler works... yes
>   checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>   checking for suffix of executables...
>   checking whether we are cross compiling... no
>   checking for suffix of object files... o
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
>   checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
>   checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
>   checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
>   checking for icc... no
>   checking for suncc... no
>   checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
>   checking for system library directory... lib
>   checking if compiler supports -R... no
>   checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
>   checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
>   checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
>   checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
>   checking for PHP prefix... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10
>   checking for PHP includes... -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php/ext/date/lib
>   checking for PHP extension directory... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
>   checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php
>   checking if debug is enabled... no
>   checking if zts is enabled... no
>   checking for re2c... no
>   configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
>   checking for gawk... no
>   checking for nawk... no
>   checking for awk... awk
>   checking if awk is broken... no
>   checking whether to enable raphf support... yes, shared
>   checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
>   checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
>   
> ...............
>            ^
>   1 error generated.
>   make: *** [php_propro.lo] Error 1
>   ERROR: `make' failed
>   64 source files, building
>
> 1 error generated.
>   make: *** [php_http_buffer.lo] Error 1
>   ERROR: `make' failed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got few tips from some existing posts related to this kind of issues.
I found the component for php5.5.10 in https://www.php.net/get/php-5.5.10.tar.gz/from/a/mirror

Followed the steps below to install pecl_http on my MAMP on Mac OS 10.8:

```
Install brew
Install autoconf using brew brew install autoconf
Download the source code for PHP 5.5.10 (or whatever version you are using) from php.net
Extract the source code into /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include
Rename the extracted file from "php-5.5.10" to "php"
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/include/php
Run ./configure
Add extension=http.so to my php.ini file
Restart MAMP
```

All my extensions are installed.

Special thanks to joshua.paling and user387049 for all the above information.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same as well. Installing was a pain because MAMP libraries are no longer publicly available. But once I got what the library components was expected to do as well, it was actually relatively simple.

You can simply download the latest php version here -: http://php.net/releases/index.php, extract it's content and insert it content below.

The path looks like this for me /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/include/php . I manually create the folder include, and then the extracted download content here in the php folder.

After that ./configure worked, and then I just did pecl install uploadprogress. Add that extension to the relevant php.ini file (for the version) -: extensions=uploadprogress.so into your php.ini

Cheers 
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

I've got this running with MAMP 3.2.1 on OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite. Here's the commands I ran:

download the php source code:
https://www.php.net/get/php-5.6.7.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror

go to the downloads folder

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

extract the tarball

```
tar -xzvf ./php-5.6.7.tar.bz2
```

rename the resulting folder to php:

```
mv php-5.6.7 php
```

move it

```
mv php /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/include/
```

install the Xcode command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

run configure and build something!

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/include/php
./configure
pecl install uploadprogress
```

Thanks to:

[Can't phpize or configure an extension in OS X 10.9 Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531262/cant-phpize-or-configure-an-extension-in-os-x-10-9-mavericks)

and

[How to fix, 'PHP' make, in Mac OS X (10.9.4)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841906/how-to-fix-php-make-in-mac-os-x-10-9-4)