# How to fix, 'PHP' make, in Mac OS X (10.9.4)?

Tags: php, macos, postgresql, makefile

I'm adding postgres support to PHP on OS X Mavericks (10.9.4).

Followed steps from [blog] (http://blog.rupey.org/post/63221360055/adding-postgres-support-to-php-on-os-x-mavericks)... fixed in between errors, and, reached till 'make'.

While performing 'make' I get the below error.
    ------ERROR------

```
users-mbp:pdo_pgsql RK$ pwd
/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql

users-mbp:pdo_pgsql RK$ make
/bin/sh /usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/include/php/ext          -I. -I/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql/include -I/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql/main -I/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql/pdo_pgsql.c -o pdo_pgsql.lo 
 cc -I/usr/include/php/ext -I. -I/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql/include -I/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql/main -I/usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql/pdo_pgsql.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_pgsql.o
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/pdo_pgsql/pdo_pgsql.c:25:
In file included from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:34:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:51:11: fatal error: 'zend_config.h' file not found
# include <zend_config.h>
      ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [pdo_pgsql.lo] Error 1
users-mbp:pdo_pgsql RK$


------ERROR------}
```

But, I could locate the files in the below directories:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_config.h

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_config.h
```

Saw a similar issue under [post] ([Having problems while try to install OAUTH with PECL in MAMP on mac OS lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717752/having-problems-while-try-to-install-oauth-with-pecl-in-mamp-on-mac-os-lion)).
-which suggests:

> If you get the following /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend/zend.h:51:11: fatal error: 'zend_config.h' file not found make sure you configure php sources. i.e. in the directory where you copied all the files run ./configure –  greg Jan 19 '13 at 2:41

Though, I've already run ./configure, the above error still occurs.

Can help me understand what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems `zend.h` is not in `/usr/include/php/Zend/` but rather in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/php/Zend/`.

Comment: Actually,     "zend.h" couldn't locate     "zend_config.h”.  
...it's true that zend_config.h is NOT under:     /usr/include/php/Zend.  

Rather I see the following two files, under:     /usr/include/php/Zend  
    zend_config.w32.h  

    zend_config.nw.h  



-Should I copy zend_config.h to the above location, manually?

Comment: You could try that or use the path of where they're located; those files are probably dependent on others as well though.

Answer (score 12):

so I found a solution that worked for me.

Head on over to your terminal and type

"sudo cp -r /usr/include/php /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/**php5.x.x**/include/"

Replace the bold lettering with the version of php you're using

then run the make command

Comment: This saved me! The default php source had all these headers missing.

Comment: Thanks. For me it has copied all to include folder but should to include/php so "sudo cp -r /usr/include/php/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/include/php"

Comment: Note the above comment from @fdrv, and that recursive cp uses capital -R.