# How to install SPL_Types for MAMP 3.0.7.3?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm having trouble installing SPL_Types with pecl for MAMP 3.0.7.3.  Note that I am ***NOT*** using the "Pro" version of MAMP.  How can I install this, or any pecl package, for the basic version of MAMP?

When I run the `pecl install pecl/SPL_Types` command, the output is:

```
pecl install pecl/SPL_Types
downloading SPL_Types-0.4.0.tgz ...
Starting to download SPL_Types-0.4.0.tgz (8,388 bytes)
.....done: 8,388 bytes
6 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I've read that with older versions of MAMP, there was an extra download available of "server components and libraries" that would supply the missing pieces.  However, that appears not to be available any longer.

What is the correct procedure now?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375772/where-to-find-mamp-server-components-and-libraries

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have autoconf installed. Try running this:

```
brew install autoconf
```

and see if that helps resolve the issue!