# Gearman PECL Extension on MAMP

Tags: php, osx-mountain-lion, mamp, pecl, gearman

I'm trying to install Gearman on Mac OS X with MAMP PRO. I use PHP 5.4.4 of MAMP. I installed Gearman using Macports

`$ port install gearman`

After that, I want to install the PECL extension but installation gives the following error;

`$ sudo pecl install gearman-beta`

```
WARNING: php_bin /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php appears to have a suffix /php5.4.4/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
running: phpize
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
building in /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-root1NxsrE/gearman-1.1.2
running: /private/tmp/pear/install/gearman/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin12.5.0
checking for PHP prefix... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4
checking for PHP includes... -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable gearman support... yes, shared
found in /opt/local
checking for gearman_client_set_context in -lgearman... yes
checking for gearman_worker_set_server_option in -lgearman... yes
checking for gearman_job_error in -lgearman... yes
checking for gearman_client_unique_status in -lgearman... yes
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin12.5.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-root1NxsrE/gearman-1.1.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/gearman -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-root1NxsrE/gearman-1.1.2/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-root1NxsrE/gearman-1.1.2/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/gearman -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/opt/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall   -c /private/tmp/pear/install/gearman/php_gearman.c -o php_gearman.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/install/gearman -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-root1NxsrE/gearman-1.1.2/include -I/private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-root1NxsrE/gearman-1.1.2/main -I/private/tmp/pear/install/gearman -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/main -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/ext -I/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/opt/local/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -c /private/tmp/pear/install/gearman/php_gearman.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/php_gearman.o
/private/tmp/pear/install/gearman/php_gearman.c:16:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_gearman.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

If I use the default system PHP (which is 5.3.26 and located at /usr/bin/php) instead of MAMP's 5.4.4, `sudo pecl install gearman-beta` successfully installs. But then I can't use `gearman.so` with MAMP 5.4.4 because they are not built for the same PHP version.

Comment: Jonny, I'm still searching for a solution but unfortunately couldn't find any.

Comment: I think I just found a solution. I'll post it now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was due to MAMP not having all the PHP sources.

I found this really helpful solution that explains how to download and configure them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175197/369326

Note that the MAMP components doesn't include the extras for any versions of PHP higher than php 5.4.10 but you can download the extras from http://php.net/releases.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try this when I have spare time.