# MAMP 2.2 / PHP 5.5.3 / Can't install PHP imagick extension

Tags: php, awk, imagemagick, mamp, imagick

We have a MAMP 2.2 install which runs PHP 5.5.3 and we've been trying to install ImageMagick. Things we've done so far:

- Installed Brew, Xcode, Xcode Command Line Tools
- Used Brew to install the actual ImageMagick binaries

Now comes the problem - attempting to install imagick either through pecl (pecl install imagick) or brew (brew install php55-imagick) fails because the PHP sources don't exist. So:

- Downloaded PHP 5.5.3 source code from php.net/releases - moved it to appropriate folder following various online tutorials (mainly this one: [Having problems while try to install OAUTH with PECL in MAMP on mac OS lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717752/having-problems-while-try-to-install-oauth-with-pecl-in-mamp-on-mac-os-lion#11175197)), tried to configure. Didn't work

The error is as follows:

```
config.status: creating main/php_config.h
awk: non-terminated string  "Darwin g... at source line 362 source file  ./conf12xr7I/defines.awk
context is
<<<  13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86"\
awk: syntax error at source line 364 source file ./conf12xr7I/defines.awk
awk: illegal statement at source line 364 source file ./conf12xr7I/defines.awk
config.status: error: could not create main/php_config.h
```

Without the PHP sources I don't seem able to install the imagick extension. This also happened with PHP 5.4.4 on MAMP 2.1.1 - same error, same file.

How do I get past the apparent error in the PHP SOURCE CODE and get this thing up and running?

Comment: Can you post lines ~360-370 of the `./conf12xr7I/defines.awk` file for us?  The first error could be from that file( like a missing `"` ) or resolving another variable etc.

Comment: I went to look for the file when I saw the error but it was always gone when I did - temporary files being deleted on a failed compile, possibly. In the end I resolved this by downloading the PECL extension and compiling it myself instead of letting the process be automated. I suspect part of the automated process was trying to use Mac native PHP instead of the MAMP version.