# Can't install memcached.so extension for MAMP's PHP 5.6.2 on OS X 10.10?

Tags: php, memcached, mamp, php-extension

I have installed memcached, libmemcached with brew, downloaded the memcached  PECL extension, compiled it, by following this tutorial -> https://donatstudios.com/OS-X-Mavericks-Memcached-PHP-Extension-Installation

And then I have copied memcached.so to MAMP's extension dir:

```
cp /tmp/memcached/memcached-2.2.0/memcached-2.2.0/modules/memcached.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/
```

And added the line extension=memcached.so into `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini`,
which is my PHP conf file according to the MAMP phpinfo.
But I get the following error in MAMP/logs/php_error.log:

```
[19-Nov-2014 09:40:16 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcached: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

What's the problem with my configuration?

How can I resolve and install this memcached extension once for all???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve thanks to these two pages:

[Having problems while try to install OAUTH with PECL in MAMP on mac OS lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717752/having-problems-while-try-to-install-oauth-with-pecl-in-mamp-on-mac-os-lion/11175197#11175197)

and

http://verysimple.com/2013/11/05/compile-php-extensions-for-mamp/

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install memcached
```

OR

```
sudo pecl install memcached
```