# php_intl extension not recognised SilverStripe

Tags: php, symfony, mamp, silverstripe

I'm using MAMP to install SilverStripe and had to enable php_intl in the ini.
After restarting MAMP multiple times, it still gives me this error:

```
ERROR [Emergency]: Uncaught Exception: This backend requires the php-intl extension IN POST /silverstripe/install.php Line 31 in C:\MAMP\htdocs\silverstripe\vendor\silverstripe\framework\src\i18n\Data\Intl\IntlLocales.php
```

I have checked all files that I could find and were related to it, but php_intl.dll is there and it's enabled in the ini.

Comment: which file did you configure to enable the extension php.ini? How you know the `php_intl` is enabled?

Comment: @goto I modified the php.ini in my C:/PHP folder. phpinfo() told me that is the one it is using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install/activate PHP "intl" extension running MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469412/install-activate-php-intl-extension-running-mamp)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.

Due to a tunnel to another DB, the connection SilverStripe tried to make was interrupted and seen as invalid.